Matlab crush with local glibc2.34 installed
I have Ubuntu20.04 and Matlab 2023b installed.
When I start simulink(part of Matlab) the program crashes with:
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../elf/dl-tls.c: 517: _dl_allocate_tls_init: Assertion 'listp != NULL' failed!,
which is well known issue with newer Matlab versions with linux OS that goes with glibc older than version 2.34.
Official bug fix proposed by MathWorks is to patch your glibc for your whole OS, which is not desirable in my case.
I saw one solution that would be suitable for me, which is installing glibc2.34 locally and then adding its path to LD_LIBRARAY_PATH variable, only while running Matlab, which would result in only Matlab using the other version of glibc.
I have followed this steps to install glibc2.34 locally. I verified that it works with command:
user@hostname[~]: ~/glibc/glibc-2.34-install/bin/ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.34
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
To oprogramowanie jest darmowe; warunki kopiowania są opisane w źródłach.
Autorzy nie dają ŻADNYCH gwarancji, w tym również gwarancji MOŻLIWOŚCI
SPRZEDAŻY lub PRZYDATNOŚCI DO KONKRETNYCH ZASTOSOWAŃ.
Autorami są Roland McGrath i Ulrich Drepper.

But after adding glibc/lib into LD_LIBRARAY_PATH, I got segfault error on simple binaries like ls:
user@hostname[~/glibc]❯ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/dsadowsk/glibc/glibc-2.34-install/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
user@hostname[~/glibc]❯ ls
Segmentation fault
user@hostname[~/glibc]❯ /opt/matlab/R2023b/bin/matlab
Segmentation fault

It looks exactly like this issue, but unfortunately I don't understand very well, how the solution works, and it doesn't work for the matlab here, as for ls command.
user@hostname[~/glibc]❯ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /lib64 /bin/ls
build  glibc-2.34  glibc-2.34-install  glibc-2.34.tar.gz
user@hostname[~/glibc]❯ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /lib64 /opt/matlab/R2023b/bin/matlab
/opt/matlab/R2023b/bin/matlab: error while loading shared libraries: /opt/matlab/R2023b/bin/matlab: invalid ELF header

How can I be able to run matlab binary with glibc2.34 installed locally and not for my whole system?
Thank you for any thoughts you have.

is /opt/matlab/R2023b/bin/matlab really an ELF binary? (file /opt/matlab/R2023b/bin/matlab will tell you.) It might be a shell script, in which case you’d have to figure out where the binary it ends up running is, and run that instead using the --library-path technique.

@StephenKitt shouldn't the OP also do export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/dsadowsk/glibc/glibc-2.34-install/lib" instead of export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/dsadowsk/glibc/glibc-2.34-install/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to avoid changing the libc used by everything? If their locally installed one comes first in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, doesn't that mean all tools will use the local one?

@terdon given the segfaults I don’t think a one-size-fits-all LD_LIBRARY_PATH is possible in this scenario. If we get past the lack of a default for LD_LIBRARY_PATH anyway (so export …="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:…" won’t work anyway), the first libc will win, so it’s either the new one or the old, not whichever one works. In the linked support solution I think the intent was just to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH in a terminal, start Matlab, and then not use the terminal for anything else.
